# How do I implement a reset for my loop counter?

Tags: java

I have an action listener that calls some methods and one of those methods counts the number of times that a loop inside of another method is run. The problem I am having is that the counter just adds to itself (I understand why I just don't know how to fix it) rather than resetting back to 0.

Here is my action listener code.

```
    public double computeIterative(double n) throws InvalidInput {            
        int a=1, b=2;
        int result = 0;
        if (n>=0) {
            if(n==0)return 0;
            if(n==1)return 1;
            if(n==2)return 2;
            for(int i = 3; i <= n; i++) {                    
                result = a+(2*b);
                a=b;
                b = result;                    
                this.getEfficiency();                    
            }                
        }   else{
                throw new InvalidInput();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

ActionListener that calls methods and sets text:

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(nField.getText());
        //Try Catch for Iterate Radio Button
        if (iterateBtn.isSelected()){
            try {                
            double result = sequence.computeIterative(n);
    int efficiency = sequence.getEfficiency();
            rField.setText(Double.toString(result));
            eField.setText(Integer.toString(efficiency));
            }
            catch (InvalidInput ex) {
            }
        }
```

The getEfficiency method counts how many times the loop inside computeIterative method is run and then sets it to a textField.

Here is my getEfficiency method:

```
    public int getEfficiency() {
        efficiency++;            
        return efficiency;
    }
```

Now obviously this will just keep adding onto itself, and I am sure that I am looking way too hard for a solution but I just cant figure it out.

Basically, after the try, catch, I need to set efficiency to 0 so that the next time the computeIterative(n) method is called, I get a proper reading.

Comment: Why can't you just write `efficiency = 0;` at the beginning of the method?

Comment: "The getEfficiency method counts...then sets it to a textField" - no it doesn't. "after the try, catch" - what try/catch? "I need to set efficiency to 0" - ok, what's stopping you?

Comment: @shmosel I added code to clarify what I meant. Like I said the problem was probably right in front of my face. Now I feel like a moron lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply add a method `resetEfficiency()`:

```
public int resetEfficiency() {
     efficiency = 0;
}
```

And then call it at the beginning of `computeIterative()`:

```
public double computeIterative(double n) throws InvalidInput {
    this.resetEfficiency();
    //rest of code goes here
    //....  
}
```

(Of course I'm assuming this is not multi-threaded or anything).

Comment: Thanks, sometimes its really easy to look over the simplest things especially after many hours of staring into a screen.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public double computeIterative(double n) throws InvalidInput {            
        int a=1, b=2;
        int result = 0;
         this.resetEfficiencyCounter(); //Call Reset if Number Got Invalid.
        if (n>=0) {
            if(n==0)return 0;
            if(n==1)return 1;
            if(n==2)return 2;
            for(int i = 3; i <= n; i++) {                    
                result = a+(2*b);
                a=b;
                b = result;                    
                this.getEfficiency();                    
            }                
        }   else{
                throw new InvalidInput();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

add new Function Named `resetEfficiencyCounter()`.

```
private void resetEfficiencyCounter(){
   this.efficiency = 0;
}
```